# Angular Growl V2 - Failing unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular Growl V2 for showing notifications. When I run Grunt test, I get this error and all the controllers that use Growl fail.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'growlProvider.globalPosition('top-center')')
```

I have injected growl in all the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. I needed to inject it in `Karma.conf.js`.